# R - use of ddply to extract p value from an ANOVA

Tags: r

I am stuck on a bit of analysis using the ddply function.

The dataframe (`long.format`) structure is as follows:

```
'data.frame':   2058 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ tertile : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 1 3 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 21 levels "age","ht","wt",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : num  57 57 65 58 59 56 63 63 68 58 ...
```

I have used ddply to perform anova of $variable across $tertile using $value as follows:

```
aovfun <- function(x)  aov(tertile~value,x)
y <- ddply(long.format, .(variable), aovfun)
```

The subsequent database gives me the intercept and slope but is there way i can extract individual P values as well?

I have attached a code for an example data.frame as below:

tertile = rep(1L:3L,9)

age=rnorm(9,60,5)

ht=rnorm(9,157,10)

wt=rnorm(9,70,5)

df <- data.frame(tertile,age,ht,wt)

long.format <- melt(df,id=c("tertile"))

Comment: Is it possible that your code is `aovfun <- function(x)  aov(value~tertile,x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 aovfun <- function(x) aov(value~tertile,x)
 ddply(long.format, .(variable), 
       function(x) summary.aov(aovfun(x))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]])[,-3]

 #  variable         V1
 #1      age 0.06676654
 #2       ht 0.23854030
 #3       wt 0.88039549
```

Comment: thanks akrun. tried your code but its coming with as error. have added in code for a sample data frame which i hope might help. thanks for trying...and sorry if these queries are too basic...just getting into R!

Comment: @user3919790. Just saw your dataset. I will test it.

Comment: perfect thanks again ankur!! saved me some time again!